# Netlify is using python version 2.7

Tags: python, netlify

I am trying to deploy a flask app on netlify. But it is using python 2.7 which I think is the reason of its failure. Here's the output log:

```
7:19:50 PM: Build ready to start
7:19:52 PM: build-image version: 081db65c3e4ce8423fedb40e7689a87de6f84667
7:19:52 PM: build-image tag: v4.3.1
7:19:52 PM: buildbot version: 2cc7c0ccf754e7f302de1daa4d80d9968804770c
7:19:52 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
7:19:52 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
7:19:52 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
7:19:52 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
7:19:52 PM: git clone https://github.com/Harshbansal8705/harsh-bansal
7:19:54 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
7:19:54 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
7:19:55 PM: Different build dir detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: '' versus '/' in the Netlify UI
7:19:55 PM: Starting build script
7:19:55 PM: Installing dependencies
7:19:55 PM: Python version set to 2.7
7:19:56 PM: Downloading and installing node v16.10.0...
7:19:56 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.10.0/node-v16.10.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
7:19:56 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
7:19:56 PM: Checksums matched!
7:19:59 PM: Now using node v16.10.0 (npm v7.24.0)
7:19:59 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
7:19:59 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
7:19:59 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
7:20:01 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
7:20:01 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
7:20:01 PM: Installing pip dependencies
7:20:01 PM: Started restoring cached pip cache
7:20:01 PM: Finished restoring cached pip cache
7:20:02 PM: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
7:20:02 PM: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.9, 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.11, 0.11.1, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.4, 0.12.5, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4)
7:20:02 PM: ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask==2.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
7:20:02 PM: Error installing pip dependencies
7:20:02 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
7:20:02 PM: Creating deploy upload records
7:20:02 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
7:20:02 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
7:20:02 PM: Finished processing build request in 10.826611849s
```

Anyone please help me with this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google search suggests that [Python 2.7 is the default](https://answers.netlify.com/t/python-version-years-out-of-date/6605) on Netlify, for various legacy reasons.

See their [Python](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#python) documentation to find out how to set the desired version:

> You can choose the Python version we use to build your site in one of the following ways:
>
> 1. Set a PYTHON_VERSION environment variable.
> 2. Add a runtime.txt file to the site’s base directory in your repository. The file must include the version number only: x.y, with no trailing newline.
> 3. Use Pipenv to specify a version and save it to a Pipfile in the site’s base directory in your repository.